# Writing a small piece of code to sum up digits in a string, through using a try-except block

Tags: python, string, try-except

Background: One of the "Finger Exercises" in my introductory textbook has me try to write such a program to teach me how to use a try-except block. The textbook is designed to accompany the '6.00x' class on edX, an MIT MOOC. This isn't part of the online class itself, but merely some practice to get me to understand try-excpet blocks.

Here is my code so far:

```
def sumDigits(s):
'''Assumes s is a string
   Returns the sum of the decimal digits in s
       For example, if is is 'a2b3c' it returns 5'''
    try:
        digitsum = 0
        for i in s:
            digitsum += int(i)


    except TypeError:
        return 'You have hit a TypeError'

    except ValueError:
        return 'You have hit a ValueError'

    return digitsum
```

So, what I'm having trouble with is knowing what to put into the except clause. The text I put into the two except clauses are there because I just wanted my program to run. I'm assuming the interpreter goes through a string like '456ab', hits 'a', then prints out the text I told it to return when it inevitably hits a ValueError. How do I get it to 'ignore' the alphabetical characters in the string, and just make use of the numbers in the string, all in the context of a try-except block?

Comment: Alternatively you could filter out the non-digit characters using `"".join(filter(str.isdigit, "dfg"))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move your `try` within the loop, and ignore the exception by using `pass` as the exception handler:

```
digitsum = 0
for i in s:
    try:
        digitsum += int(i)
    except ValueError:
        pass  # ignore non-digit characters
```

You won't hit a `TypeError` here unless any `i` is a type of object that `int()` cannot handle; e.g. anything not a number or a string:

```
>>> int({})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'
```

Comment: This method gets an accurate sum while ignoring characters that don't sum.  However, Ignoring Exceptions is a BAD PRACTICE in general. Part of the purpose of exceptions is to choke on unexpected input and just ignoring or "eating" the exception is a common source of difficult to find bugs.  I don't think it was the purpose of the original exercise to use exceptions this way.

Comment: @mcgyver5: Why would ignoring exceptions *for specific applications* be a bad practice? Python exceptions are not just *errors*; they are signals to tell you about exceptional situations. For some usecases ignoring those situations explicitly is **fine**.

Comment: @mcgyver5: That's why an exception in a *single method* is being caught here. This is entirely Pythonic, **especially** when the OP is trying to learn about how to use them!

Comment: @mcgyver5: Don't compare Python exceptions usage with other languages, BTW. Again, let me stress that exceptions are not just there to signal bugs in the code.

Comment: @mcgyver5: To illustrate: the Python `StopIteration` and `GeneratorExit` exceptions are used *exclusively* to signal specific signals that **have** to be passed outside of the normal `return` or `yield` codepaths. Python code catches those exceptions **all the time**, including ignoring them.

Comment: Look past pythonic vs not pythonic to determine if a coding practice makes sense.  Python does not exist in a bubble by itself.

Comment: @mcgyver5: So, in Python, stating that *Ignoring Exceptions is BAD PRACTICE* is entirely, patently and worryingly *wrong*.

Comment: @mcgyver5: Of course Python doesn't exist in a bubble by itself. But that doesn't mean that Python therefor **has** to stick to conventions of other languages. Those other languages don't dictate how programming is to take place; they don't live in a bubble either. As it stands, Python best practices are *different* in places. because this is a different language in places.

Comment: @mcgyver5: I invite you to read the [Handling Exceptions page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions) on the Python wiki, which discusses Python exceptions in comparison to other languages, explicitly. Specifically, it handles writing *cleaner* code through the use of exceptions and exception handling, thereby *preventing* bugs.

Comment: The conventions in other languages are there for a reason:  So much confusion from the program continuing merrily along when it received bad input as your code snippet does.  And I accept that there are cases where one might do this - not always a bad practice.  I don't accept that python is special.  I think that a lesson teaching exceptions would expect the student to use them to let the user know a bad input was received, not hide that fact.

Comment: @mcgyver5: But that's where the conceptional difference lies. This is not about bad input. This is about acknowledging that the input contains *more* than just digits, and handling those efficiently and elegantly. This is not about ignoring *bad* input, the input is perfectly legal and fine. You **want** to handle the input correctly, the way it is handled is *by design*.

Comment: @mcgyver5: Now, if I were using a *blanket* except handler, catching all exceptions indiscriminately, then you might have a point. [I've critisized people for blanket exception handling more than once](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A100297+blanket+except). Note that in this answer I tell the OP **not** to catch `TypeError` exceptions; you should not *get* a `TypeError` if the input is a string.

Comment: @mcgyver5: However, if you condemn all Python exception handling that silences specific exceptions, you'll be a long way away from ever mastering this language. Each programming language has its own idiom and strengths, learn to play them to your advantage. The way Python handles exceptions is one of Python's strengths.